# How to upload multiple Android projects in one repository?

Tags: android, git, github, configuration

[image]

I have multiple Android projects and I want to upload them on Github but on a single repository. because I have other python projects, Websites, and Java projects. So I want to create only one repository for each Language or platform. Does anyone have an idea how can I do? I already push Python, Java, and C project.

Answer (score 1):

On Android File > New > New Module > then Create a Module or Import a Module

That will help to work on the same repo having different android projects
that's how this open source does it https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upload them on multiple branches.

Another option would be to create multiple repositories and add each one of them as a submodule into a single repository. In that way, you wouldn't have to manage such a huge codebase at a single repository while being able to manage them at a single place